# how to run third party binaries in bazel

Tags: bazel

I am newbiew to Bazel, I am trying to use thrift 10 in my bazel build and I need to run thrift binary to generate the thrift files. But I have conflicting version of thrift in my linux box, and somehow build is using wrong version while building.

Can someone help me how to solve this problem? Remember I have `thrift.bzl` which generates the thrift generated files..

Here is the current third party definition

```
cc_library(
    name = "thrift",
    srcs = [
        "lib/libthrift.a",
        "lib/libthrift.so",
        "lib/libthrift.so.0.10.0",
        "lib/libthriftc.a",
        "lib/libthriftc.so",
        "lib/libthriftc.so.0.10.0",
        "lib/libthriftz.a",
    ],
    hdrs = glob(["include/**/*.h"]),
    includes = ["include"],
    linkshared = 0,
    tags = make_symlink_tags([
        "lib/libthrift.a",
        "lib/libthriftc.a",
        "lib/libthriftz.a",
        "lib/libthrift.so",
        "lib/libthriftc.so",
        "lib/libthrift.so.0.10.0",
        "lib/libthriftc.so.0.10.0",
        "lib/libthriftz.so.0.10.0",
    ]),
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
    deps = ["@boost_repo//:boost"],
)

filegroup(
    name = "thrift_gen",
    srcs = ["@thrift_repo//:bin/thrift"],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
```

`thrift.bzl`

```
_generate_thrift_cc_lib = rule(
    attrs = {
        "src": attr.label(
            allow_files = True,  # FileType(["*.thrift"]),
            single_file = True,
        ),
        "thrifts": attr.label_list(
            allow_files = True,  # FileType(["*.thrift"]),
        ),
        "base_name": attr.string(),
        "service_name": attr.string(),
        "service": attr.bool(),
        "gen": attr.string(default = "cpp"),
        "_thrift": attr.label(
            default = Label("@thrift_repo//:thrift_gen"),
            executable = True,
            cfg = "host",
        ),
    },
    output_to_genfiles = True,
    outputs = _genthrift_outputs,
    implementation = _generate_thrift_lib,
)
```

And here is the error

```
INFO: Found 11 targets...
ERROR: ...source/mlp/storage/services/thrift/BUILD:10:1: Generating mlp/storage/services/thrift/umm_geometry_constants.cpp failed (Exit 127).
external/thrift_repo/bin/thrift: error while loading shared libraries: libthriftc.so.0.10.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: From skimming your question (on mobile) it sounds you have the right direction but probably just have a small bug of wiring. You can take a look at rules_scala for a working thrift scala example which might help you. Essentially you need to declare all inputs and outputs so that Bazel will isolate your build

Comment: Have you figured out a solution to this question?